# Python function does not accept the parameter

Tags: python, function, parameters

why does func2 not accept the parameter x?

```
def func1():
    x = 1
    return x

def func2(x):
    y = x+2
    print(y)

func2()
```

TypeError: func2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Comment: `func2(func1())`

Comment: You defined `func2` to require a parameter, but then you're calling it without a parameter...

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass in a parameter when calling the function `func2()`, as this is what the function uses to perform the `y = x+2` calculation. Without this parameter, the function wouldn't know what `x` is defined as in its local scope.

E.g `func2(5)` would print `7` as `x` would be `5` in func2's local scope.

Answer (score 2):

The `func2()` function is defined to accept a single argument, x, but no arguments are passed to it when it is called. As a result, an error is raised, because the function does not receive the `x` argument that it is expecting.

To fix this problem, you need to pass the `x` argument to the func2() function when you call it, like this:

```
x = 1 # or any number
func2(x)
```

Comment: ok but how do i use an input dependent value that is created in one function and use it in another?

Comment: You can create a global variable in the first function and set its value to the input-dependent value. Then, you can access the global variable in the second function. `global value = input()`

Comment: are globals the only way? if yes then what use does "return" have?

Comment: No, global is not the only way. If you are defining a function only to take input from user, you can call that function like this to get its value using return: `input_value = take_input_from_user()` and in the function `return input_value`

Comment: it doesn't work and i don't know why

Comment: Globals aren't just not the only way to do this, they are arguably the *worst* way to do this.  (I can think of worse ways but they involve `ctypes` and buffer overflows.)

Answer (score 1):

`func2` accepts a parameter, but you haven't provided one.

If you want to pass it the value that `func1` returned, you can assign `func1`'s result to a variable, and then pass that variable as the argument to `func2`:

```
result = func1()  # call func1, assign result to a variable called "result"
func2(result)     # call func2 with that result as its argument
```

The `x` within `func1` contains the value that is assigned to the variable `result`, and that same value is passed to `func2` as its `x` parameter.

You can also skip the intermediate step of assigning a variable and just do:

```
func2(func1())  # call func2 with the result of func1() as its argument
```

Comment: i've tried all answers and none worked except the globals. i feel like i use a completely different version of python.

Comment: @DennyStoll This answer should work with the code you presented in your question. Take that code and replace the wrong last line (`func2()`) with the code from this answer.

Comment: @dennystoll if you get an error with an answer, you should say what the error is (the same way you included the typeerror in your original question, which was good).  My guess is you’re just typo’ing something, but nobody can help you if they don’t know what went wrong.  I ran the code in my answer (along with your function definitions) and it printed “3”.

Answer (score -1):

The code snippet when executed returns the Type Error: func2() missing 1 positional argument as when you defined func2 you made it compulsory to pass the argument x to func2 function (positional argument) and when the function call is made for func2() you have not passed the required argument.

If you are thinking that the value x that you defined inside the function func1() is not being accepted by func2. This is because the variable x is local variable and also you cannot pass the value to function while defining it. You pass the value to a function when you are calling it.

So if you want that the value x is should be accepted by func2 function you can write func2(func1) in place of func2().